# Speed up THREE.CanvasRendering

Tags: three.js

I have created a sphere geometry and wrapped a texture on it as follows.

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("RESOURCES/360.jpg");
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;      
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(500,60,40),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:texture,overdraw:true}));
mesh.scale.x = -1;
scene.add( mesh );
```

I move my camera around the sphere. When i use WEBGL renderer everything works fine but when i switch to canvas rendering mode the movement is not smooth. It gets stuck in between. Is there any way i could speed up the canvas rendering. What effect does the value radius , segment width and height have on performance of renderer.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The canvas renderer is slow since it probably isn't using the GPU. SphereGeometry takes the parameters: radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, phiStart, phiLength, thetaStart, thetaLength. Reduce the number of segments and performance might improve. A smaller canvas might help too. IMO unless you're doing something very simple, or are prepared to write an ultra-simplified canvas version, use the WebGL renderer or don't bother.

Comment: yes the performance increases when i reduce value for height and width segments but the texture on the sphere gets worse. I have noticed more segments more spherical is your geometry but performance drops.I want my app to run on IE10 and low which has no support for WEBGL.